# Session unset, or session_destroy?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between session_unset() and session_destroy() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303311/what-is-the-difference-between-session-unset-and-session-destroy-in-php)

What is the best for security, and if the session is unset are load times better the next time the session has to accessed rather than recreated?

Comment: could you clarify your question ?

Comment: There is session destroy and unset, what are the differences?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. From the accepted answer, I think the user means `unset()` other than `session_unset()`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Unset will destroy a particular session variable whereas `session_destroy()` will destroy all the session data for that user.

It really depends on your application as to which one you should use. Just keep the above in mind.

```
unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data

session_destroy(); // will delete ALL data associated with that user.
```

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up, session destroy seems safer :)

Comment: If your goal is to destroy all session data for that user, yes.

Comment: Yes, it would be safer that way, as in the logout link.

Comment: I think OP was asking about session_unset vs session_destroy differences. unset ans session_unset are different functions.

Comment: For readers: Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.

Comment: This answer is confusing . "session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called. " - php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Answer (score 9):

Something to be aware of, the `$_SESSION` variables are still set in the same page after calling `session_destroy()` where as this is not the case when using `unset($_SESSION)` or `$_SESSION = array()`. Also, `unset($_SESSION)` blows away the `$_SESSION` superglobal so only do this when you're destroying a session.

With all that said, it's best to do like the PHP docs has it in [the first example for `session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#refsect1-function.session-destroy-examples).

Comment: Any idea why the $_SESSION variables are still set after calling session_destroy() ?

Comment: @wkm, "`session_destroy()` destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, `session_start()` has to be called. " - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed "Data" seems ambiguous. The session variables contain "data." I suppose `session_destroy()` destroys the contents of the session file for that session, or destroys the entire file. In my case, it deletes the row in my database for that session id. So, as I understand it, the `$_SESSION` variable is populated by values from those "data" sources at the beginning of the request. Then `$_SESSION` may be modified during execution. Finally, when the request is finished, PHP will "write" to the "data" (file/db) and empty the `$_SESSION` variable. Is that about right?