# Difference between unset($_SESSION[]), session_unset() and session_destroy() in PHP

Tags: php, session

I need help regarding session in php

I tried this code

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['one'] = "Hello";
$_SESSION['two'] = "World";
$_SESSION['three'] = "Welcome to session";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

It prints

```
array (size=3)
  'one' => string 'Hello' (length=5)
  'two' => string 'World' (length=5)
  'three' => string 'Welcome to session' (length=18)
```

Then I unset the session one

```
unset($_SESSION['one']);
echo "Session one unset and only session two and three exist";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

And it prints

```
Session one unset and only session two and three exist
array (size=2)
  'two' => string 'World' (length=5)
  'three' => string 'Welcome to session' (length=18)
```

Then if I destroy the session

```
session_destroy();
echo "Session Destroyed <br />";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

But nothing happens and I can still print the session as

```
Session Destroyed 
array (size=2)
  'two' => string 'World' (length=5)
  'three' => string 'Welcome to session' (length=18)
```

But if i use `session_destroy();` again it gives me a warning

> Warning: session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session

And instead of `session_destroy()` code if i use unset

```
session_unset('two');
echo "Session two unset";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

All the session variables get unset and i cant access the session three variable
It prints

```
Session two unset
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Instead of using `session_unset('two');` if I use `session_unset();` then I also it gives me the same result.

So what is the actual difference between `unset($_SESSION['one'])`, `session_unset('one')`, `session_unset()` and `session_destroy().`

I googled it and everywhere I got the answer that `session_destroy()` is used to destroy the whole session (but in the code above I can still access the session variable) and `session_unset('one')` is used to unset only a single session variabele (But in the code above if I use `session_unset('one')` all the session variables get unset).

So Please help me understand how session works, Also what code should be used while logging our users, `session_unset()` or `session_destroy()`.

Comment: Do format heading of Q in manner to get exact idea of issue with few words only! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session unset, or session\_destroy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697822/session-unset-or-session-destroy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its pretty simple,

**session_unset** — Free all session variables, but session id will not be destroy

**session_destroy** — Destroys all data registered to a session, to call this function first session should be registered.

**unset($_SESSION['VARIABLE_NAME'])** - This will unset variable value which you passed.

In your example, calling **session_destroy()** directly is not correct, as a result you can see the values of variable which are there in session, you can call session_destroy for registered session.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: 1. Can you explain how to call `session_destroy()`
2. how can we register a session
3. Is `session_unset()` and `session_unset('VARIABLE_NAME')` have the same effect. because after using `session_unset('VARIABLE_1')`, I cant access `session_unset('VARIABLE_2')`
4. Which of these should i use in logout page

Comment: 1. session_destroy(), you can call directly. 2. you can call session_register() function to register a session. 3.No session_unset('VARIABLE_NAME') will unset variable from the session, and session_unset() will remove all variables form the session. So in your case you should use session_destroy, which will completely destroy all the session variable, and session ids, and it will logout the user.

Answer (score 3):

After using `session_destroy()`, the session cookie is removed and the session is no longer stored on the server. The values in `$_SESSION` may still be available, but they will not be on the next page load.

As per [PHP](http://www.bing.com/fd/ls/GLinkPing.aspx?IG=abbfb8b13bd34a218ebc0c9efed6e41c&&ID=SERP,5138.1&SUIH=YNdEu1DiCOs-z9z5Leuabg&redir=aHR0cDovL3BocC5uZXQvbWFudWFsL2VuL2Z1bmN0aW9uLnNlc3Npb24tdW5zZXQucGhw)

```
void session_unset ( void )
```

The `session_unset()` function frees all session variables currently registered and do not take any parameters.

`unset($_SESSION['name']);` will delete just the name data.

Comment: You are correct, after `session_destroy()` the values in the session variables are no longer available on the next page load.
But what is difference between `unset($_SESSION[])` and `session_unset()`

Comment: OK got it, 
That means we should use only `session_unset()` and not session_unset('one').

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that it is destroyed but the memory is not released yet, so you can still look at it.  Whereas unset sets it to null.