# php session and cookies destroy

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am new to php, especially for cookie and session, so if I delete the session or cookie using

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
//for session

setcookie("user", "", time() - 3600);
//for cookie
```

it will :
1) delete the session or cookie for only one specific visitor that have run the code above
2) or delete all the session or cookie for all visitor

From logic, it should be 1, but I just want to ensure that. anyone who explain that would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697822/session-unset-or-session-destroy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start()` creates a cookie on the client with the default name of PHPSESSID and an id that quite unique and very hard to guess. It will also resume the session if the cookie has already been created and hasn't been expired yet.

`session_regenerate_id()` regenerates the session ID and moves over the session data to a new ID set by `$SESSION['key'] = 'value';` this is handy with login systems to refresh the session ID on successful login for a defense against [session attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081025/php-session-fixation-hijacking).

`session_destroy()` removes session data stored on the server for that session id and requests the client to delete that cookie, however to save performance this is done routinely and not immediately.

You are also able to create named sessions, and specifically start and destroy them but usually this is not needed.

You are able to [handle session data](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) and store the data in a database if you so prefer.

Comment: A side note and often forgotten, using [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to prevent concurrent writes. This releases the session lock to be used with simultaneous scripts executing (e.g ajax) using `session`.

Comment: @dbf I was, completely unaware of this, so thanks for sharing. I just realized now why `session_start()` returns a boolean.

Comment: Your welcome ;) and now you can edit questions without a hassle and review :D

Comment: Nou dat valt best mee moet ik zeggen ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is specific to the user. Write some code that involves starting a session and check in your browser and you will see the cookie on your machine. There is a whole [documentation section on how PHP handles sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove session cookie of personal visitor & remove session file on server.
setcookie(..) will create cookie on this visitor.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to set a session is

```
$_SESSION['session_name'] = 'value of the session';
```

`session_destroy()` will all the sessions.

You also need session_start() at the very top of the code to start any 
type of php session. Same goes for set cookie and destroy cookie.

The best way to learn php is to first read the book and then 
you can go digital learning. You can't learn from online, I suggest 
 you get a php book; go through the entire thing then come online
 write small piece of code and start small files as a test bed.

Paper first, going digital next; it takes some time so give yourself a project to work on. Sorry to get carried away, but that's how I recommend you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

`session_destroy();` will delete all sessions stored on the server for this user. If you are looking for a specific session like username use `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` to create it. And then unset it using `session_unset('username');` Be careful to keep session start at the top of the document.