# Logout requering to click twice

Tags: php, session

Good morning.

Building a web app as to manage automobiles as you can see [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtfcH.png).

What you see in the previous image is the file index.php, configured to show different things if the user has done login or not:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Welcome to the Automobiles Database</h2>
    <?php
if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
    echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['error'])."</p>\n");
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
if ( isset($_SESSION['success']) ) {
    echo('<p style="color: green;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['success'])."</p>\n");
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
?>


    <!-- without login -->
    <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        echo '<p><a href="login.php">Please log in</a></p>';
        echo '<p>Attempt to <a href="add.php">add data</a> without logging in</p>';
    } ?>


    <!-- with login -->
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
        echo '<table border="1"><thead><tr><th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>Mileage</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>';
        $smtp = $pdo->query("SELECT autos_id, make, model, year, mileage FROM autos ORDER BY make");
        while ($row = $smtp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo("<tr><td><b>");
            echo($row['make']);
            echo("</b></td><td><b>");
            echo($row['model']);
            echo("</b></td><td><b>");
            echo($row['year']);
            echo("</b></td><td><b>");
            echo($row['mileage']);
            echo("</b></td><td><b>");
            echo("<a href=\"edit.php?autos_id=".$row["autos_id"]."\">Edit</a> / <a href=\"delete.php?autos_id=".$row["autos_id"]."\">Delete</a>");
            echo("</b></td><tr>\n");
        }
        echo '</table>';
        echo '<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entry</a></p> <p><a href="?logout">Logout</a></p>';
        if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_unset();
        }
    } ?>



</div>
</body>
```

The problem i'm facing has to do with the link "Logout", which is as following:

```
echo '<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entry</a></p> <p><a href="?logout">Logout</a></p>';
```

If i click once, [this is the result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB8iI.png).

This logs out the user as expected, but i want it to [reach this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK6wE.png) right away (which is the index.php without login) and to achieve this i'm having to click twice in the link...

Logout.php:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
header('Location: index.php');
```

How can I do it?

BP

Comment: use this  if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {     session_unset();      } , outside <?php if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {

Comment: On Logout you need to `destroy` or `unset` the session variable... 
`unset($_SESSION['name']); // will delete just the name data` or
`session_destroy(); // will delete ALL data associated with that user.`... [Click here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697835/3453169)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSOM8VY7WTRF

Comment: the problem remains with that

Comment: have u check above link ?

Comment: redirect directly to   echo '<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entry</a></p> <p><a href="./Logout.php">Logout</a></p>';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed *Logout.php* to:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

and the Logout link to:

```
echo '<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entry</a></p> <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>';
```

Now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your "?logout" to the url of the logout.php page hope it may solve the problem

```
<html>
'<p><a href="add.php">Add New Entry</a></p> <p><a href="?logout">Logout</a></p>'; ?</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this adding `session_destroy();` at the end

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);
unset($_SESSION['email']);
session_destroy();
?>
```