# Is it a good idea to `session_destroy()` when a site's user logs off or in?

Tags: php, web

I'm building a small website project and I am curious if there would be any reason not to do `session_destroy()` when a user wants to log off? What about just before logging in a new user? The site request a user to be logged in before interacting with the site in any way.

Comment: `session_destroy()` is the recommended method to destroy a PHP session.

Comment: Well if not session_destroy, I am curious what did you had in mind ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. It's actually the common way to do so. If you want an example see the docs for [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) there's a complete example with everything you need to do.

Comment: What would be the uncommon way ?

Comment: You can also loop through all session variables and manually unset every variable... 
There is also a function called [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP's built in session management, then it is what you should do at each logout. This way you can make sure that a new user at the same computer can't reuse any saved data that has been stored for the previous user before.

An other way is `session_unset`, but that, unlike `session_destroy` does not delete all session data such as data in the session storage. More about the difference: [What is the difference between session_unset() and session_destroy() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303311/what-is-the-difference-between-session-unset-and-session-destroy-in-php)