# PHP Unset Session Variable

Tags: php, session

I'm a noob programmer so I apologies in advance for any obvious mistakes. I've spent the past week creating a product database kinda thing. I've got too the point where I can add products using a form, view all products added etc. I've being using sessions which are created via the form input data. I'm struggling to include get a delete product page working, I've tried using unset to clear the variable but can't get it too work.

ADD Product page which sets the session variable:

```
$_SESSION['Products'][] = $_POST; //is how i set the session on the add products page. 

unset $_SESSION['Products'][]; //is how i have tried to clear the session although it does not work.
```

Any point in the right direction will be appreciated!

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['Products']);` is enough

Comment: and to clear all session's use session_unset();

Comment: Giving it a bit of thought I think I would need to do more than unset the session variable. I would need to delete the entire array for that product from my product list page. My bad

Comment: t3kz I think that would delete the entire list of products rather than one, i'll have a go

Comment: @BradleyBoothman so using `unset($_SESSION['Products']);` fixes right?

Comment: @Thamilan Unfortunately not!

Comment: @BradleyBoothman So you need to hold `$_SESSION['Products']` but with empty array am I right?

Comment: Would you like me to show you the site im building it on? I think so though yes

Comment: Got it working, thanks!!!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can unset session variable using:

1. [`session_unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) - Frees all session variables (It is equal to using: `$_SESSION = array();` for older deprecated code)
2. `unset($_SESSION['Products']);` - Unset only Products index in session variable. (*Remember*: You have to use like a function, not as you used)
3. [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) — Destroys all data registered to a session

To know the difference between using `session_unset` and `session_destroy`, read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312574/5447994). That helps.

Comment: Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION.

Comment: What exactly is `deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION` ?  Are there (deprecated) ways to use sessions in PHP other than `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: unset($_SESSION['Products']); this works for me. thx

Answer (score 16):

I am including this answer in case someone comes to this page for the same reason I did. I just wasted an embarrassing amount of time trying to track the problem down. I was calling:

```
unset($_SESSION['myVar']);
```

from a logout script. Then navigating to a page that required login, and the server still thought I was logged in. The problem was that the logout script was not calling:

```
session_start();
```

Unsetting a session var DOES NOT WORK unless you start the session first.

Answer (score 14):

Unset is a function. Therefore you have to submit which variable has to be destroyed.

```
unset($var);
```

In your case

```
unset ($_SESSION["products"]);
```

If you need to reset whole session variable just call

```
session_destroy ();
```

Comment: Nitpicking here: `unset` is a language construct and *not* a function.

Comment: Yes. It is a language construct. But php manual itself categorize unset as a variable handling function as well. www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php . Any way I just needed to highlight the fact that variable name should be passed to it.

Comment: Yes but the difference is there. It's not a function.

Answer (score 11):

If you completely want to clear the session you can use this:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Actually both are not neccessary but it does not hurt.

If you want to clear only a specific part I think you need this:

```
unset($_SESSION['Products']);
//or
$_SESSION['Products'] = "";
```

depending on what you need.

Comment: $_SESSION["XYZ"] = ""; will not clear the memory. The variable will still exist, and isset() will still return true on it

Answer (score 3):

`unset` is a function, not an operator. Use it like `unset($_SESSION['key']);` to unset that session key. You can, however, use `session_destroy();` as well. (Make sure to start the session with `session_start();` as well)

Comment: `unset` is *not* a function, but a language construct

Answer (score 3):

**Destroying a PHP Session**

A PHP session can be destroyed by session_destroy() function. This function does not need any argument and a single call can destroy all the session variables. If you want to destroy a single session variable then you can use unset() function to unset a session variable.

*Here is the example to unset a single variable*

```
<?php    unset($_SESSION['counter']); ?>
```

*Here is the call which will destroy all the session variables*

```
<?php    session_destroy(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// set
$_SESSION['test'] = 1;

// destroy
unset($_SESSION['test']);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['Poducts'] = 1; // set
unset($_SESSION['Products']); //unset
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answer about unset are correct but one thing is needed to be corrected. If you did not use `session_start()` the `unset()` will never work. I recommend doing it this way

```php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['productID']);
```