# index.php not running on my browser

Tags: php, redirect, wamp

I built an online examination system web application. I installed wamp server and imported necessary databases. At first, when I run this localhost/oes/index.php
in my browser, it ran correctly and gave required output.

but now  I run the same localhost/oes/index.php URL but it automatically executing another file of the same project which is localhost/oes/stdwelcome.php.
please immediately give me guidance how to fix this.
Below is my code for index.php:

```
 <?php

 /*
***************************************************
*** Online Examination System                   ***
***---------------------------------------------***
***                                             ***
*** Author: chandra sai & omkar                     ***
*** Title:  Student Authentication              ***
***************************************************
*/

 /* Procedure
*********************************************

 * ----------- *
 * PHP Section *
 * ----------- *
Step 1: Event to Process...
        Case 1 : Register - redirect to Registration Page.
        Case 2 : Authenticate


 * ------------ *
 * HTML Section *
 * ------------ *
Step 2: Display the Html page to receive Authentication Parameters(Name & Password).

*********************************************
*/

      error_reporting(0);
      session_start();
      include_once 'oesdb.php';
/***************************** Step 1 : Case 1 ****************************/
 //redirect to registration page
      if(isset($_REQUEST['register']))
      {
            header('Location: register.php');
      }
      else if($_REQUEST['stdsubmit'])
      {
/***************************** Step 1 : Case 2 ****************************/
 //Perform Authentication
          $result=executeQuery("select *,DECODE(stdpassword,'oespass') as std from student where stdname='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name'],ENT_QUOTES)."' and stdpassword=ENCODE('".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)."','oespass')");
          if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
          {

              $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
              if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r['std'],ENT_QUOTES),(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)))==0)
              {
                  $_SESSION['stdname']=htmlspecialchars_decode($r['stdname'],ENT_QUOTES);
                  $_SESSION['stdid']=$r['stdid'];
                  unset($_GLOBALS['message']);
                  header('Location: stdwelcome.php');
              }else
          {
              $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";
          }

          }
          else
          {
              $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";
          }
          closedb();
      }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Online Examination System</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oes.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <?php

        if($_GLOBALS['message'])
        {
         echo "<div class=\"message\">".$_GLOBALS['message']."</div>";
        }
      ?>

      <div id="container">

                <div class="header">
                <img style="margin:10px 2px 2px 10px;float:left;" height="150" width="150" src="images/logo.png" alt="OES"/><h3 class="headtext"> &nbsp;Online Examination System </h3><h4 style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;margin:0 0 5px 5px;"><i>...because Examination Matters</i></h4>
            </div>
     <form id="stdloginform" action="index.php" method="post">
      <div class="menubar">

       <ul id="menu">
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['stdname'])){
                          header('Location: stdwelcome.php');}else{  
                          /***************************** Step 2 ****************************/
                        ?>

                      <!--  <li><input type="submit" value="Register" name="register" class="btn btn-primary" title="Register" /></li>-->
           <li><div class="aclass"><a href="register.php" title="Click here  to Register">Register</a></div></li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="page">

              <table cellpadding="30" cellspacing="30">
              <tr>
                  <td>User Name</td>
                  <td><input type="text" tabindex="1" name="name" value="" size="16" /></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Password</td>
                  <td><input type="password" tabindex="2" name="password" value="" size="16" /></td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                      <input type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Log In" name="stdsubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                  </td><td></td>
              </tr>
            </table>


      </div>
       </form>

    <div id="footer">
          <p style="font-size:70%;color:#ffffff;"> Developed By-<b>chandra sai & omkar</b><br/> </p><p>Prepared under the guidance of Prof. A.Ananda Rao sir.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: we need to see index.php, file permissions, vhosts and hosts file please :)

Comment: can i fix this by reinstalling wamp server..please someone respond immediately

Comment: As @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs said we need to see your files like index.php, vhosts ... To be able to give you an answer

Comment: nothing is wrong with wamp. post code of index.php so we can help.

Comment: code for index.php added

Comment: change `error_reporting(0)` to `error_reporting(1)` and page will show errors.

Comment: I think it's because you already submitted once. Now you've got $SESSION['stdname'] set which redirect you to stdwelcome.php.

That's why now when you're trying to access index.php it redirects you to stdwelcome.php. Try to clear your $SESSION variable.

Comment: What I'm supposed to do in order to clear that $SESSION variable. PLEASE explain a bit more. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586585/php-unset-session-variable/37586700