# How to unset $_SESSION variable?

Tags: php

Good morning guys, I have set this code and i would like to unset $_SESSION["username"], IF $_POST["logout"] isset

```
 <?php 


  if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["name"];        


    if(isset($_POST["logout"]))      
      unset($_SESSION["username"]);

?>
```

Comment: `unset($_SESSION["username"]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between session\_unset() and session\_destroy() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303311/what-is-the-difference-between-session-unset-and-session-destroy-in-php)

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you start the session? And your indenting has no relation to how the code is actually being executed, `$_SESSION["username"]` will always be unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem some bad logic in code, try

```
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["name"];        
}

if(isset($_POST["logout"])) {
    unset($_SESSION["username"]);
}
```