# Why session_unset() doesn't have any effect after session_destroy()?

Tags: php, session, unset

By reading up on [session_unset()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) and [session_destroy()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) I've found notes that `destroy` does not clean up variables and such.

1. How come the code below does not clean up the `$_SESSION` superglobal, which it should by its documentation?
2. Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Snippet to reproduce:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['x'] = 1;

// If you uncomment this, `session_unset` works as intended.
session_destroy();

// It doesn't matter if you call unset, it won't have any effect
// as session_destroy was called.
session_unset();

fwrite(STDERR, var_export($_SESSION, true));
// prints: array ('x' => 1), even though session_unset was called
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312574/7849549 see this answer

Comment: @JaiDixit I saw that before posting. it doesn't explain me my issue.

Answer (score 0):

because session_destroy() will remove all sessions related with that user.
[here document](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is about the implementation of default session driver. (See [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)).

When `session_destroy` is called, PHP trigs `destroy` method of session class handler. perhaps it destroy only data without to touch `$_SESSION` and when `session_unset` is called, it verifies on each `$_SESSION` items, if key of item is persisted, it delete it, if not, it does nothing.

Finaly, when you call `session_destroy` first, all data is destroyed, so `session_unset` can't do anything while `$_SESSION[$key]` isn't persisted.

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
{
   global $data_persisted; //fictive variable containing persisted datas as array
   if(isset($data_persisted[$key])
   {
      unset($_SESSION[$key]);
   }
}
```

Finaly, after call respective of `session_destroy` and `session_unset`, `$_SESSION` still will have its datas.